# Saxon XQuery Memory Management

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, xquery, saxon

So I have been working with Saxon quite a bit recently and am having some concerns about its memory management ability.

From what I understand Saxon does not take data as streams which means that if I need to make comparisons on 1000 tuples all 1000 tuples are allocated memory. This seems like a flawed system to me. Is there a reason behind this other than limitations in java?

I feel like this really makes XQuery a less viable alternative to SQL and JDBC which supports streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, XPath allows navigation anywhere in the source document, for example you can write things like `//x[@y = //z/@y]` - such queries are clearly not streamable.

Saxon-EE does support streaming for a restricted subset of queries. The streaming capability is currently much more advanced in XSLT than in XQuery, simply because the XSL working group has been working on this area extensively over the last few years. Saxon-EE 9.6 supports pretty well all the streaming capability of the draft XSLT 3.0 specification.

Details are here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!sourcedocs/streaming

this also includes information about Saxon's capability for streaming XQuery

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll check the link out!